# What does the Action ADD in kubernetes-fabric8 watch API mean?

Tags: kubernetes, fabric8, fabric8-maven-plugin

What does the Action ADD in fabric8 watch API mean? My initial understanding of it is to add a resource, but I tested it and a bunch of ADD Actions were triggered.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Fabric8 Kubernetes Client's `WatchEvent` basically maps to Kubernetes [`pkg/watch/json`](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/watch/json/types.go#L32). So `EventType` in it is basically a `String` value which is sent by Kubernetes API server as a response and you need to handle what you need to do on the type of event. It can have these values: `ADDED`, `DELETED`, `MODIFIED`, `BOOKMARK`, `ERROR`. When you start the watch without any `resourceVersion` as a parameter, it would just start with resource version set to `0`. It starts watch from the beginning and you see `ADD` actions being triggered for the resources which are already in the cluster. I think you must have seen this behavior when you use `kubectl` as well:

```
~/go/src/github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/kubernetes-model/kubernetes-model-core : $ kubectl get pods -w
NAME                                           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
<These are pre existing resources listed since start of watch>
nginx-deployment-54f57cf6bf-4swvr              1/1     Running   1   <        2d5h
nginx-deployment-54f57cf6bf-4swvr-clonem6sg6   1/1     Running   1          2d5h
testpod                                        1/1     Running   1          2d5h
testpod-cloneb5fkz                             1/1     Running   1          2d5h

<You should be able to see events after you do some changes>
testpod                                        1/1     Running   1          2d5h
```

If you go ahead and create some more resources, you should be able to see more `ADDED` actions being triggered. On modifying, you should be seeing `MODIFIED` events as well. These are sent by Kubernetes APIServer and Fabric8 Kubernetes Client just deserializes them into Java objects.

So, while watching I would suggest you to handle all the cases depending upon your situation inside the `eventReceived()` call like this:

```
// Latch for Watch termination
final CountDownLatch isWatchClosed = new CountDownLatch(1);
try (KubernetesClient client = new DefaultKubernetesClient()) {
    client.pods().inNamespace(namespace).watch(new Watcher<Pod>() {
        @Override
        public void eventReceived(Action action, Pod pod) {
            logger.log(Level.INFO, action.name() + " " + pod.getMetadata().getName());
            switch (action.name()) {
                case "ADDED":
                    logger.log(Level.INFO, pod.getMetadata().getName() + "got added");
                    break;
                case "DELETED":
                    logger.log(Level.INFO, pod.getMetadata().getName() + "got deleted");
                    break;
                case "MODIFIED":
                    logger.log(Level.INFO, pod.getMetadata().getName() + "got modified");
                    break;
                default:
                    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Unrecognized event: " + action.name());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onClose(KubernetesClientException e) {
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "Closed");
            isWatchClosed.countDown();
        }
    });

    // Wait till watch gets closed
    isWatchClosed.await();
} catch (InterruptedException interruptedException) {
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "Thread Interrupted!");
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
```

I hope this clears your understanding of Fabric8's WatchEvent types.